# Nested `for` loop on big array of objects is creating memory leak

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to anaylze more than 100k objects in an array to find patterns. I built some nest for loop to run over all the array items.

```
// const allPairs = [...] array with more than 100k objects
const patterns = [];

for (let i = -5; i < 5; i++) {
  for (let j = -5; j < 5; j++) {
    for (let k = -5; k < 5; k++) {
      for (let l = -20; l < 20; l++) {
        patterns.push({
          pairs: allPairs.filter((pair) => {
            return (
              pair.varA > pair.value * i &&
              pair.varB > pair.value * j &&
              pair.varC > pair.value * k &&
              pair.average > l
            );
          }),
          name: `Pattern A ${l}-${i}-${j}-${k}`,
        });
        patterns.push({
          pairs: allPairs.filter((pair) => {
            return (
              pair.varA < pair.value * i &&
              pair.varB < pair.value * j &&
              pair.varC < pair.value * k &&
              pair.average < l
            );
          }),
          name: `Pattern B ${l}-${i}-${j}-${k}`,
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Basically I'm trying filter my array in order to find which pattern has the more objects.

This is always generating.
`FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

I did try to increase node memory `export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=5120"` but it fails as well.

Objects look like this

```
{
  id: 111339,
  symbol: 'HELLO',
  tested: true,
  successful: false,
  average: 0.010298,
  value: 1.4,
  varA: 0.51118,
  varB: -0.1545,
  varC: -0.1547,
  varD: -0.3592,
  varE: 0.51118,
  varF: -0.1545,
  varG: -0.1547,
  varH: -0.3592,
  varI: 0.51118,
  varJ: -0.1545,
  createdAt: 2022-06-10T15:30:09.170Z,
  updatedAt: 2022-06-10T16:29:08.324Z
}
```

Any recommendations to make this more efficient?

Comment: Hi elyrico, could you please also specify what pattern are you looking for and how a single array entry is formed? It is not really easy to understand it from the code...

Comment: hello @Drago96 , I edited the question, let me know it needs more info

Comment: Hi @elyrico, I don't see any "value" attribute inside the object. You are using it in the filter functions...
Also, do you need to have those two entry seperately even if the "pattern name" is the same? (you are doing a very similar operation twice)

Comment: @Drago96 sorry I did try to simplify my code in order to make it more readable and I deleted some other important values. I added now `value` and updated pattern names.

Comment: also I want to add more patterns in the future by changing `<` and `>` combinations

Comment: Hi elyrico, honestly I don't see any big issue with your code. I'm looking into heap memory now and seeing that it's related to the object references. If I were you, I would save the index of the element instead of passing a reference. I mean something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/3vgqtd15/

Comment: The resulting array will have a slightly different structure, but it contains the same informations, and MAYBE will be lighter on the heap size. Let me know how it goes :)